# Android error on click

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am building an Android Studio App, but everytime I click on a button, the app crashes.
This is the Java MainActivity file:

```
    package com.example.alex.exemplu1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void buton1()
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    }
```

The only thing I added is the buton 1 function, I want it to change the page.
This is my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:text="hello World!"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>
 <Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:text="welcome"
     android:onClick="buton1()"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the app to switch the page from "Mainpage" to the page named "layout"
Can you please help me?

Comment: post your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your xml replace this

```
<Button
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:text="welcome"
 android:onClick="buton1"
 />
```

in java

```
     public void buton1(View v){

 setContentView(R.layout.layout);
```

}`

Comment: Thank you sir, but the Code You gave me only shows a message, I want to switch to another XML Page, can you please Tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear! Do you want to change from MainActivity to another activity when pressed in the button of the MainActivity you must create a second Activity lets call it SecondActivity create the activity using Android studio it will add xml file for the SecondActivity by default.

in xml file add

```
 <Button
 android:id="@+id/changeButton_id"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="change"/>
```

Then in MainActivity.java file add this

```
Button changeButton=(Button)findViewByid(R.id.changeButton_id);
changeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent=new 
             Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `setContentView` when button clicked.

`setContentView` inflate's layout resource file and attach to activity. It must be called in `onCreate`

If you want to change layout in your activity, you must inflate your `R.layout.layout`, remove old views from `R.layout.activity_main` and add inflated view into layout.

But all this way isn't right. Try to add all your content in `activity_main` and use `View.setVisibility(VISIBLE/INVISIBLE/GONE)` for views to show and hide their.

Comment: So it's practically like a HTML Page with multiple DIV that are shown or not, depending on users actions, right? Very good advice